# Rotate MKMapCamera around a certain point in MKMapView, not center

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I want to rotate a `MKMapCamera` around a certain point in the MKMapView which is not necessarily the center point.
It should look something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXKFw.gif)

As you can see on the example, the camera rotates around the cursers location. This is what i pretty much want to achieve in code.

EDIT:
I wrote some sample code that achieves this with the `.Standard` map type. It uses the compass heading to rotate the `MKMapCamera`. Sadly, this solution doesn't work with the `.SatelliteFlyover` map type. Any solutions for that?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let locationManger = CLLocationManager()
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.800013, 13.042174)

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        /*---Setup Map---*/
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.showsBuildings = true
        mapView.showsCompass = true
        mapView.mapType = .Standard

        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta: 0))

        mapView.setCamera(MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate:
        offsetPosition(coordinate, radius: 50, heading: 0),
        fromEyeCoordinate: offsetPosition(coordinate, radius: 20, heading: 180), 
        eyeAltitude: 50), animated: true)

        /*---Setup Location Manager---*/
        locationManger.delegate = self
        locationManger.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        let heading = newHeading.magneticHeading

        mapView.setCamera(MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate:
        offsetPosition(coordinate, radius: 50, heading: heading),
        fromEyeCoordinate: offsetPosition(coordinate, radius: 20, heading: heading + 180), 
        eyeAltitude: 50), animated: false)
    }

    /*---Set offset of specified coordinate---*/
    func offsetPosition(coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius:Double, heading:Double) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {

        let offsetLatitude = cos(heading.toRadiant()) * radius
        let offsetLongitude = sin(heading.toRadiant()) * radius

        var offsetPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinates)
        let metersPerPoint = MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude(coordinates.latitude)

        offsetPoint.y += offsetLatitude / metersPerPoint
        offsetPoint.x += offsetLongitude / metersPerPoint

        return MKCoordinateForMapPoint(offsetPoint)
    }

}

extension Double{
    func toRadiant() -> Double{
        return self / 180 * M_PI
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done anything yet? Or what is the problem here?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp I added some sample code that should explain the problem further